# Displaying function evaluation and successful step counts with MATLAB ODE solvers

Tags: matlab

I have been asked to solve some ODEs with MATLAB solvers displaying the number of successful steps and that of function evaluations. Trouble is, I have no idea how to display them, and the slides from the teacher haven't helped, just like a Google search for [MATLAB ode solvers display function eval count](https://www.google.it/search?q=MATLAB+ode+solvers+display+function+eval+count&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=Ji0bVN-NNseg8weCuIGQDg) and a search on mathworks.com for [viewing function evaluation number with ode solver](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/?search_submit=answers&query=viewing+function+evaluation+number+with+ode+solver&term=viewing+function+evaluation+number+with+ode+solver), apparently. So, how do I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign a "sol" structure as the output for your ODE solver, after which you can use `sol.stats` to display the statistics.

For example:

```
tspan = [0, 20];
y0 = [2; 0];
Mu = 1;
ode = @(t,y) vanderpoldemo(t,y,Mu);

sol  = ode45(ode, tspan, y0)

sol.stats
```

sol looks like this:

```
sol = 

     solver: 'ode45'
    extdata: [1x1 struct]
          x: [1x60 double]
          y: [2x60 double]
      stats: [1x1 struct]
      idata: [1x1 struct]
```

And sol.stats look like this:

```
nsteps: 59
nfailed: 10
nfevals: 415
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yep, problem solved. Thanks. Is `nsteps` the total number of steps or that of successful ones?

Comment: The number of successful ones. More info here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/odeset.html#f92-1016858

Comment: And `successful` and `failed` in what sense?